# Custom ABC class: __new()__ takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to implement a plugin based file uploader which can upload files to different services. It loads all the python modules from a directory and then calls them based on the service to upload to.

I have a simple BaseHandler which is just an abstract base class for all plugins

```
import abc

class BaseHandler():
   __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

   @abc.abstractmethod
   def start(self,startString):
      return
```

I have a simple plugin which inherits from BaseHandler

```
from BaseHandler import BaseHandler

class Cloud(BaseHandler):
    def start(self,startString): 
        return
```

And the actual code which loads plugins and calls them

```
import logging
import os
import sys
from BaseHandler import BaseHandler

all_plugins = {}

def load_plugins():
    plugin_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)),"Handlers")
    plugin_files = [x[:-3] for x in os.listdir(plugin_dir) if x.endswith(".py")]
    sys.path.insert(0,plugin_dir)
    for plugin in plugin_files:
        mod = __import__(plugin)
    logging.info('Plugins have been loaded from the directory '+plugin_dir)
    for plugin in BaseHandler.__subclasses__():
        logging.info('Plugin:'+plugin.__name__)    
    return BaseHandler.__subclasses__()

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
loadedPlugins = load_plugins()

for plugin in loadedPlugins:
    all_plugins[plugin.__name__]= plugin.__class__
    handle = all_plugins[plugin.__name__]()
```

When I try to create the actual object of the plugin in the last line of the script

```
    handle = all_plugins[plugin.__name__]()
```

I get an error `TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)`.

Edit: added full trace back

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\TestCopy\Test.py", line 24, in <
module>
    handle = all_plugins[plugin.__name__]()
TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are registering the *meta class*, not the plugin itself;

```
>>> BaseHandler()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class BaseHandler with abstract methods start
```

I think you meant to store the plugin itself:

```
all_plugins[plugin.__name__] = plugin
```

The `__class__` attribute is the `BaseHandler` class instead; `plugin` objects are classes, not instances.

Comment: Tried your suggestion. Am getting the same error after inheriting from     object

Comment: @Gokul: Updated answer; you are registering the wrong object.

Comment: That worked great . Thanks but what would happen if the loaded plugin file had multiple classes. How can we create an object of a particular class

Comment: @Gokul: You'd already load all those classes, and your code would create instances of them all (and discard them again). Add them to a list, or a dictionary? I have no idea what you are trying to do, what it means to have *multiple* plugins of the same type, how your program treats multiple plugins, what ordering they need to have, etc. Not enough info, and too broad for comments. :-)